# Error in installing graph-tool in Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: python, python-3.x, installation, ubuntu-18.04, graph-tool

I followed the installation instructions in the website:

https://git.skewed.de/count0/graph-tool/-/wikis/installation-instructions

for installing graph-tool on Ubuntu 18.04, but when I write "sudo apt-get install python3-graph-tool" in the terminal, it gives me the following error:

Reading package lists... Done

Building dependency tree

Reading state information... Done

Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.

The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:

python3-graph-tool : Depends: libboost-context1.67.0 but it is not installable

```
                  Depends: libboost-iostreams1.67.0 but it is not installable

                  Depends: libboost-python1.67.0 but it is not installable

                  Depends: libboost-python1.67.0-py38 but it is not installable

                  Depends: libboost-regex1.67.0-icu63 but it is not installable

                  Depends: libc6 (>= 2.29) but 2.27-3ubuntu1 is to be installed
                  Depends: libgcc-s1 (>= 3.4) but it is not installable

                  Depends: libgomp1 (>= 9) but 8.4.0-1ubuntu1~18.04 is to be installed

                  Depends: libstdc++6 (>= 9) but 8.4.0-1ubuntu1~18.04 is to be installed
```

E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.

Does anyone know how I can fix it?

Comment: This might be more in Super User -forum's scope. But basic things. `apt-get update` and `apt-get install --fix-missing` sometimes fix this kind of problems.

Comment: This user received help on the [graph-tool mailing list](http://main-discussion-list-for-the-graph-tool-project.982480.n3.nabble.com/Error-in-installing-graph-tool-in-Ubuntu-18-04-td4028288.html), and ultimately resolved the issue.

Answer (score 1):

try to change the distribution

deb [ arch=amd64 ] https://downloads.skewed.de/apt DISTRIBUTION main

of the options on the page (bullseye, buster, sid, bionic, eoan, focal, groovy), only "focal" worked correctly for me.